Drowned son returns while dad is out of town
I've been trying to find this movie for a while now. A husband and wife had a son and the son ended up drowning in the ocean behind the house. The parents had a search party go out and look for the body but the couldn't find him. One stormy night the little boy pops up and the mother went all hysterical. Meanwhile the dad is out of town, so the mom just had the little boy go lay down. 
Shortly afterwards, weird stuff started happening and it turns out  that the little boy actually let a demon use his body to come back and kill his parents for him because he felt like they neglected him and that's why he died because they weren't paying any attention to him. I believe its an American movie, but I don't know the title or director. Had to be early 90's. 

Bad explanation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Look_Now?

Maybe "Trilogy of Terror II" (1996)  Story II: Bobby

It has been some time since Bobby "accidentally" drowned, leaving his
  mother Alma (Lysette Anthony) depressed and guilty. However, while her
  husband is away on business, she determines to raise her son from the
  dead. Armed with a magic book and a "Key of Solomon" (in this case, a
  talisman rather than a book), she conjures dark forces to bring her
  son back. Before going to bed, a vicious thunderstorm approaches the
  luxurious beach mansion. Hearing a knock, she opens the door to
  discover her son. After cleaning him up, she begins to make him feel
  at home again. However, all doesn't work out when Bobby goes
  completely mad and begins to terrorize his mother in the dark house
  with a sledgehammer and a butcher knife. The mother soon realizes that
  it isn't Bobby who returned to her, but a demon that had taken his
  place, as he says "Bobby hates you, Mommy, so he sent me instead,"
  revealing his demon-like face and the screen blacks out.

